# Save WooCommerce Order details in custom table

Tags: php, sql, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I have created a custom database in table `order-master` in which I will save WooCommerce order `total amount`, `shipping charges` and `token`.
For this, I have edited `paypemts.php` file, code is below:

```
<?php
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/canadiapharma.com/wp-config.php' );
global $woocommerce;
global $wpdb;
echo '<h3>Custom Calculation :</h3>';
$amount_2 = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total();
$ship_raw = floatval( preg_replace( '#[^\d.]#', '', $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_shipping_total() ) );
$ship = $ship_raw - 3600;
echo '<strong>Shipping :</strong>';
echo $ship; 
$nano=WC()->cart->cart_contents_total;
echo '<br>';
$total_amt = $nano+$ship;
echo '<strong>Total :</strong>';
echo $total_amt;
echo '<br>';
$salt = 'dAta_EnC!=';
$token_raw = base64_encode($total_amt. $salt);
$token = preg_replace(sprintf('/=/', $salt), '', $token_raw);
echo '<strong>Token :</strong>';
echo $token;
$wpdb->query("INSERT INTO order_master (payment_amt, ship, token) VALUES ('$total_amt', '$ship', '$token')"  );
?>
```

This code works fine and stores the data to the database. But it stores the data as soon as the `checkout.php` page loads. So, I made some changes and created an `onclick` event on `Place Order` button in `checkout.php` page.

OnCLick Event:

```
<?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_button_html', '<button type="submit" class="button alt" name="woocommerce_checkout_place_order" id="place_order" value="' . esc_attr( $order_button_text ) . '" data-value="' . esc_attr( $order_button_text ) . '" onclick="dbinsert()">' . esc_html( $order_button_text ) . '</button>' ); 
        ?>
```

dbinsert():

```
<script>
        function dbinsert() {
            var myKeyVals = { amount : <?php echo $total_amt; ?>., ship : <?php echo $ship; ?>., token : <?php echo $token; ?> }

            var saveData = $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: "savedata.php",
                        data: myKeyVals,
                        dataType: "text",
                        success: function(dbinsert) { alert("Save Complete") }
            });
            saveData.error(function() { alert("Something went wrong"); });
                    }
        </script>
```

`onclick` event executes perfectly but doesn't know why data is not going into the database. Below is my `savedata.php` file.

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$total_amt = $_POST['amount'];
$ship = $_POST['ship'];
$token = $_POST['token'];
$stmt = $wpdb->query("INSERT INTO order_master (payment_amt, ship, token) VALUES ('$total_amt', '$ship', '$token')"  );
$stmt->bindparam('payment_amt', $total_amt);
$stmt->bindparam('ship', $ship);
$stmt->bindparam('token', $token);
if($stmt->execute())
{
  $res="Data Inserted Successfully:";
  echo json_encode($res);
}
else {
  $error="Not Inserted,Some Probelm occur.";
  echo json_encode($error);
}
?>
```

Please help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try by changing your ajax url `url: "savedata.php",` to `url: "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php?action=save_order_data');?>"` and add below code in your theme's function.php

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_save_order_data', 'save_order_data');
add_action('wp_ajax_save_order_data', 'save_order_data');
function save_order_data() {
     global $wpdb;
     $total_amt = $_POST['amount'];
     $ship = $_POST['ship'];
     $token = $_POST['token'];
     $stmt = $wpdb->query("INSERT INTO order_master (payment_amt, ship, token) VALUES ('$total_amt', '$ship', '$token')"  );
     $result = $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare($stmt));

     if($result)
     {
         $res="Data Inserted Successfully:";
         echo json_encode($res);
     }
     else {
         $error="Not Inserted,Some Probelm occur.";
         echo json_encode($error);
     }
}
```

**Updated:**
 There is an error in `var myKeyVals = { amount : <?php echo $total_amt; ?>., ship : <?php echo $ship; ?>., token : <?php echo $token; ?> }`. Change your `var myKeyVals` as below:

```
var myKeyVals = { amount : "<?php echo $total_amt; ?>", 
                  ship : "<?php echo $ship; ?>", 
                  token : "<?php echo $token; ?>" }
```

You need to write php code in `""` in javascript.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nothing happened. What could be the problem? Is my `savedata.php` code is fine?

Comment: first check that `function save_order_data() ` is called or not ?

Comment: No luck with that too. BTW please tell me how to check if the function  `save_order_data()` is called? Because I checked it using `alert()` but now it's not showing any alert.

Comment: check by putting `die("function called");` in `save_order_data()` function

Comment: I changed `myKeyVals` to `var myKeyVals = { amount : 100, ship : 50, token : 123456 }` and data got inserted in table. So I think there is a problem in `myKeyVals` when trying to `echo` PHP variables. BTW I also got `Something Went Wrong` alert popup.

Comment: Glad that it helped you :)

Comment: For me it ended up being... url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',